# ImportError: PyQt4 is not installed

Tags: python, pyqt4, jupyter-notebook, python-import, importerror

I try to use the `py_entitymatching` framework to find duplicates in [this dataset](https://sites.google.com/site/anhaidgroup/projects/magellan/py_entitymatching).

To label the data it uses PyQt4.
So when I try to execute the labeling command I get an error

[image]

Though as you can see PyQt4 is installed on my machine and I can import it.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks

---

**Update:**

When I try to import QtGui I get the following error:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/oliver/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so: undefined symbol: __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length
```

All the packages mentioned below have been installed

- Qt4
- SIP
- PyQt4
- PyQt5

Any other thoughts?

Comment: try `from PyQt4 import QtGui`. Or maybe you have to install `Qt4`

Comment: Hi @Oblue your package has been incorrectly installed as your error is showing. The best thing to do would be to deinstall everything and reinstall it with `pip`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your PyQt package is not installed, even if the first line says that your package is installed.

Try to install it with pip and see if it does make a change

If you are using `python2`

```
sudo pip install SIP

sudo pip install PyQt
```

If you are using `python3`

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4
```

---

**Update**

> `from PyQt4 import QtGui
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   ImportError: /home/oliver/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so: undefined symbol: __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length`

Looking at your error, it seems your compilation did go wrong.

One possible solution would be to deinstall `python`, reinstall it and install `PyQt` again through `pip`

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened to me, you need to install the 64-bit version of pyqt4. you can install it [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4).
Once you install it correctly I think it will work correctly.